# Displaying a part of an image in libGDX - looks stretched

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm trying to build an progress bar in `libGDX`, for that I have one full horizontal image and in two lines I trying to display 2 different widths of that image:

imageFull:
[image]

```
imageFull.draw(batch,10,80,600,50);
imageFull.draw(batch,10,20,100,50);
```

the result is:
[image]

Its looks like when the width is 'small' its stretched and looks bad.

Why I can't display only part of the image without destroying the left side of the image?

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior. If you stretch a image without keeping it's aspect ratio it will deform, it does not know the stretchable part by itself.

[9-patch](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches) will help you here but you cannot simply draw the sprite as you are doing now (maybe with `SpriteDrawable` though?).

If I where you I would use the [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) `Actor` named `ProgressBar`. Feed that a 9-patch image, then it should stretch correctly. Or just use a `Image` if you want to control it yourself, and feed this image a ninepatch.

A quick way to create a ninepatch is to specify it's stretching regions yourself by hardcoding it.

```
texture = new NinePatch(yourTexture, A, B, C, D)
```

Where ABCD corresponds to the following image:

[image]

Now create a Scene2D `Image` with that ninepatch and it should stretch properly.

If you have a this texture already in a `Atlas` you can also supply the line `split:a,b,c,d` to the image data in the .atlas file and Scene2D will automatically pick it up as a ninepatch.

If you don't want to use Scene2D and/or ninepatch (but I recommend you to use it) you have to code the behavior yourself. Or cut the texture up yourself and stick the caps on the left and right side of your rectangle. But Scene2D is invented for this and a ton more GUI functionality.

Comment: Well the reason I tried that approach as I described is that I tried the `ProgressBa`r Actor with 9 - patch, and it worked pretty good, but when I setting a small values (1/100 - 6/100) that are less then 9-patch image width I get bad results- sides are actually pushing through each other. If not that issue everything else works nice.